# Retrieve the content of a page requiring authentication

Tags: python, json, authentication, python-3.x, python-requests

I have access to an admin page by using a basic HTTP authentication system.

This page loads data using JavaScript by retrieving JSON data from another URL I can see in the Firefox Web Dev tools (the combination `Ctrl+Shift+I`, then going in the Network tab and reloading the page)

If I copy and paste this URL in the same instance of my browser, I retrieve the JSON data I need.

So:

1. Using Firefox, I connect to the admin page and provide the username/passwd.
2. Using Firefox Webdev toolbox, I retrieve the URL used to retrieve the JSON data I want.
3. I copy and paste this URL and get the JSON data I need, ready to be parsed.

Now, I would like to do the same automatically using Python 3.

I use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to make it easier. However, if I try to retrieve directly the URL found in step 3, I get an `401 Authentication` error:

```
import requests
url = "http://xxx/services/users?from=0&to=50"
r = requests.get(url, auth=('user', 'passwd'))
r.status_code
>>> 401
```

I can do an authenticated request on the admin URL (something like `http://xxx/admin-ui/`) and I can retrieve the content of the web page, but it doesn't contain anything interesting since everything is loaded in JavaScript from that JSON data coming from the URL in step 3...

Any help would be more than welcome!

Comment: try fetching cookies you get and use them when doing `requests.get`

Comment: @laike9m Thanks for your suggestion! I tried to retrieve `r.cookies` but got an empty item: `<<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>[]>`. Any idea?

Comment: what about browsers? is there any cookie you could see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use form-based authentication, not HTTP Basic Auth as I originally thought.

So first I needed to login to the first URL in order to retrieve a auth cookie:

```
url = "http://xxx/admin-ui/"
credentials = {'j_username':'my_username','j_password':'my_passwd'}
s = requests.session()
s.post(url, credentials)
s.cookies
>>> <<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>[Cookie(version=0, name='JSESSIONID', value='...>
```

Then I could connect to the second URL using this cookie and retrieve the data I needed:

```
url2 = "http://xxx/services/users?from=0&to=50"
r = requests.get(url2, cookies=s.cookies)
r.content
>>> (a lot of JSON data! \o/)
```